# How to change timezone in php?

Tags: php, mysql, date

Hello I have hostgator web hosting and since their server are in America and I live in Europe my timezone in php is USA.How can I change timezone because I insert date and time in mysql.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `date_default_timezone_set` in php

Example

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Vienna');
```

Comment: What about mysql timezone? Because some of the fields may have default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or may be mysql NOW() function in queries?

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
date_default_timezone_set
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Following link will help you to find your timezone European

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.europe.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a DateTime Object, use `date_timezone_set` http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

Answer (score 0):

ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Los_Angeles');

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-change-timezone/

other way to change timezone.